# How long should I wait to take my parents on B2 visa to USA?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, h1b-visas

My H1 visa was processed and soon I will be flying to the USA. I want to take my mom and dad as well but the USA has no such policy for H1 visa holders. All I know is, they can come to visit me on a B2 Visa.

But I am not sure how much time I should wait and stay in the USA so that I can bring my parents on B2.

Comment: What exactly is your source of concern? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to know is there a specific time period one has to.wait if he/she has newly migrated to USA and wants to bring there parent on tourist Visa? What are formalities and considerations if some one wants to invite parents to USA?